# Insert string array result into a gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, arrays

I have this methode which should return the column name from my sql query result.
All I want is to insert and display the result in a gridview.
This is my methode:

```
    protected string[] GetColumnsofServiceIDList_By_Name()
    {
        var custName = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["cusName"]);
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        Exception etemp = null;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AP;Initial Catalog=Info;User Id=sail;Password=******;App=EntityFramework"))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sqlStatement = " My sql query here ";
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para1", custName);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para2", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        for (int i =0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            result.Add(reader.GetName(i));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                etemp = e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();

                }
                if (etemp != null)
                {
                    throw etemp;
                }
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

I want the above methode to somehow be insterted into a gridview and then view that on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) So something like

```
GridView1.DataSource = result;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Note** you can get rid of

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();

            }
```

Because to ensure that connections are always closed, openning the connection inside of a using block ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block